# Storing nested structs with mgo

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I'm trying to build a mongo document from a go struct that is heavily nested, and I'm running into a problem with the transition from go struct to a mongo object. I've built a *very* simplified version of what I'm trying to work with here: http://play.golang.org/p/yPZW88deOa

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

type Square struct {
    Length int 
    Width int
}

type Cube struct {
    Square
    Depth int
}

func main() {
    c := new(Cube)
    c.Length = 2
    c.Width = 3
    c.Depth = 4

    b, err := json.Marshal(c)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(c)
    os.Stdout.Write(b)
}
```

Running this produces the following output:

```
&{{2 3} 4}
{"Length":2,"Width":3,"Depth":4}
```

Which makes complete sense. It seems either the Write function or the json.Marshal function has some functionality that collapses the nested struct, but my problem comes when I try to insert this data into a mongo database using the mgo function `func (*Collection) Upsert` (http://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo#Collection.Upsert). If I use the `json.Marshal()` function first and pass the bytes to `collection.Upsert()`, it is stored as binary, which I don't want, but if I use `collection.Upsert(bson.M("_id": id, &c)` it appears as a nested struct with the form:

```
{
    "Square": {
        "Length": 2
        "Width": 3
    }
    "Depth": 4
}
```

But what I want to do is upsert to mongo with the same structure as I get when I use the `os.Stdout.Write()` function:

```
{
     "Length":2,
     "Width":3,
     "Depth":4
}
```

Is there some flag I'm missing that would easily handle this? The only alternative I can see at this point is severely cutting down on the readability of the code by removing the nesting of the structs, which I really hate to do. Again, my actual code is way more complex than this example, so if I can avoid complicating it even more by keeping things nested, that would definitely be preferable.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I think using the `inline` field tag is the best option for you. The [mgo/v2/bson documentation](http://godoc.org/launchpad.net/mgo/v2/bson#Marshal) states:

```
inline     Inline the field, which must be a struct or a map,
           causing all of its fields or keys to be processed as if
           they were part of the outer struct. For maps, keys must
           not conflict with the bson keys of other struct fields.
```

Your struct should then be defined as follows:

```
type Cube struct {
    Square `bson:",inline"`
    Depth  int
}
```

**Edit**

`inline` also exists in `mgo/v1/bson` incase you are using that one.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly the type of flag I knew I was overlooking.

Comment: Perhaps the documentation could have been worded better and mentioned "embedded" fields.